# Detecting URL that includes trailing /#

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a question:

If in my case my URL is constructed like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/#
```

I want to call up a "under construction" page in my public folder.

How can I do that?

Comment: URL on serverside never contains `#` or anything after it (called ["fragment identifier"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier)), as browsers never send it to the server. Thus, trying to detect it there is futile. (If you *really* need to, you can detect it with JavaScript on clientside; but I suggest you have an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).)

Comment: Amadan, you should write that comment as an answer.